# How to create a 3D scatter plot with prediction and real labels in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, neural-network, scatter

I am trying to compute a 3D scatter plot using only matplotlib to create a 3D scatter plot that shows the samples x(s) with the true label y(s) and a predicted label py(s) that I computed in my neural network. I have the training data set x_train(s), y_train(s) and predicted_label_y(s). The x_train(s) is defined by 3 coordinates (hence the need to use 3D scatter plot) and y_train(s) only one label from 0 to 3.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

for s in range(S):
    x_1 = x_train[s, 0]
    x_2 = x_train[s, 1]
    x_3 = x_train[s, 2]

    ax.scatter(x_1, x_2, x_3, c='red', marker='o')

    if label_train[s] == 0:
        ax.scatter(x_1, x_2, x_3, c='blue', marker='x')

    if label_train[s] == 1:
        ax.scatter(x_1, x_2, x_3, c='blue', marker='x')

    if label_train[s] == 2:
        ax.scatter(x_1, x_2, x_3, c='blue', marker='x')

    if label_train[s] == 3:
        ax.scatter(x_1, x_2, x_3, c='blue', marker='x')

    ax.set_xlabel('x')
    ax.set_ylabel('y')
    ax.set_zlabel('z')
    plt.show()
```

In this code S is S = x_train.shape[0]. With this code I'm only having one point plotted and I don't know why. Can anyone help? The code is this one but I'm sure it is wrong so if this is not the way to go please let me know.

```
x_train is a np array: [[ 10.65603173  -7.60668833  10.50487706]
 [  1.37060917   5.77154929   9.44959297]
 [  6.90931665   0.02749131   8.1297622 ]
 [  1.73834422   5.50747998  12.84575516]
 [  3.30720989   6.03518948  12.20305176]
 [  5.63104051   1.99336929   7.19346422]
 [  7.4703742    6.24133255  11.79579689]
 [  0.54025982   7.93152252   6.86388278]
 [ -6.95596825  -9.69598657   7.96463793]
 [ 10.799844     8.19037532   6.2165125 ]
 [  5.40377909   5.08256751  11.18677783]
 [  6.75773139  -9.30573778   7.15086554]
 [ 11.07038227   9.03542293  12.78946283]
 [ -7.68452653   4.32297443  13.47487071]
 [  3.01605013  -8.78931769   9.26483574]
 [ -7.71225814  12.72526188  11.07333285]
 [  4.97457471  -2.06696162  12.43925348]...

This is how y_train looks like: 
[3. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 2. 2. 1. 2. 3. 1. 2. 3. 1. 0. 2. 2. 2. 0. 3. 3.
 3. 1. 1. 1. 2. 1. 1. 3. 3. 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 0. 2. 0. 1. 0. 0. 2. 1. 3. 3.
 3. 0. 2. 2. 1. 0. 3. 3. 3. 3. 1. 1. 3. 3. 1. 2. 0. 3. 3. 3. 0. 3. 3. 0.
 3. 0. 3. 0. 0. 1. 1. 2. 0. 2. 0. 3. 1. 0. 2. 3. 1. 0. 0. 3. 1. 3. 1. 1.
 1. 1. 3. 3.]
```

Comment: Your code works for me. I see 20 points, but I used random numbers. What's your `x_train.shape`?

Comment: Your code works for me as well, make sure you have properly defined S and that the for loop is working as you would expect.